# iToast never disappears in my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new in iOS. I want to use iToast in my App. I followed [toast-notifications-ios](https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios/blob/master/README.md)

First when I created my `iToast.m` I got four errors on these lines:

```
[label release];
[imageView release];
view = [v retain];
iToast *toast = [[[iToast alloc] initWithText:_text] autorelease];
```

I always have problem with `release` and `autorelease` in different examples. I use iOS 5.1, xCode 4.3.3. I saw many examples using them but I always got errors on them. Can you let me know why?

When I commented the first third error lines and use the forth one like:

```
iToast *toast = [[iToast alloc] initWithText:_text];
```

I could run the project but when the Toast pops up, it never disappears. I used this line as written in `README.md`:

```
[[[[iToast makeText:NSLocalizedString(@"Something to display a very long time", @"")] 
                    setGravity:iToastGravityBottom] setDuration:iToastDurationShort] show];
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just started out you are probably using Automatic Reference Counting, or ARC. Using this the compiler handles the memory for you and renders `retain`, `release`,and `autorelease` for you. You can either disable ARC for your project or go through the supplied code and make it ARC compliant by translating `retains`, `releases`, and `autoreleases`.

This explains the differences and how to transition:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks, I disabled Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) and iToast became disappear.